# SmartValidator - manually calling validate with groups

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation, spring-web

Spring 4.3.2

I need to call SmartValidator.validate() manually and I need it utilize the validation groups that I have defined on the target entity. The javadoc says this...

> "This variant of validate() supports validation hints, such as
>   validation groups against a JSR-303 provider (in which case, the
>   provided hint objects need to be annotation arguments of type Class)."

```
void validate(Object target,
          Errors errors,
          Object... validationHints)
```

For some reason, I cannot find much information or examples on using "validationHints". So I have been trying things like the following...

```
validator.validate(targetEntity, errors, new Class[]{ValidationGroup1.class});

validator.validate(targetEntity, errors, ValidationGroup1.class);
```

So far, it just completely ignores my groupings. It always calls all validators. Any ideas?

Thanks!

===================================

Update: The javadoc also says this..

> "Note: Validation hints may get ignored by the actual target
>   Validator, in which case this method should behave just like its
>   regular Validator.validate(Object, Errors) sibling."

This sounds like what's happening. But it doesn't give any clue as to why it might ignore it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright then.
It seems the 'answer' is to not use Spring for this. Here is my workaround...

```
import javax.validation.Validator;
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation> violations = validator.validate(targetEntity, new Class[]{group1.class, group2.class});
```

Then I convert Set to Spring FieldErrors (since everything is already configured to run Spring). Kind of a clusterf***, but at least it's working now.

Comment: Springs `SmartValidator` works for me inside a SpringBoot 2 App as expected, my guess is that it depends on which underlying `Validator` springs has configured.